# "Within X miles" search in mongodb

Tags: nosql, mongoid

I want to be able to find zip codes are that within a specific radius of distance from another zip code. I have some code from [this source](http://joshhuckabee.com/simple-zip-code-perimeter-search-rails). But it is an SQL implementation using ActiveRecord. It is precisely the implementation I want but only with MongoDB. Help!

Comment: You should look into mongoid-geo gem. https://github.com/kristianmandrup/mongoid-geo

Comment: As of august 2011, the linked project seems to have ceased development. Instead you might want to look at https://github.com/ryanong/mongoid_spacial.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the MongoDB [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) and the Mongoid  [indexing docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/indexing.html).

```
class Zip
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :code
  field :location, :type => Array

  # make sure to rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
  index [[ :location, Mongo::GEO2D ]], :min => 200, :max => 200
end

# at the console
Zip.create(:code => 1001, :location => [0, 0])
Zip.create(:code => 1002, :location => [1, 1])
Zip.create(:code => 1003, :location => [2, 1])
Zip.create(:code => 1004, :location => [-1, -1])

Zip.where(:location => { '$near' => [0, 0] } ).count
# 4
Zip.where(:location => { '$near' => [0, 0], '$maxDistance' => 1.5 } ).count
# 3
Zip.where(:location => { '$near' => [0, 0], '$maxDistance' => 1 } ).first
# 1
```