# Create post-code based service

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, location

I want to create a United Kingdom(London focused) post code based application. For instance, one of the basic queries would be:

- User comes and types their post code, determine the n most nearby objects to the post code they typed in.

I am using noSQL(MongoDB) and I benefit from DB native geo-spatial objects.

1. How do I link geo-spatial coordinates to UK postcodes?
2. Is this long-lat to postcode conversion the right approach?
3. Is there a service available to cover that part?
4. How do you convert from London post code to latitude and longitude
   so that you can measure distance?

Comment: 1. [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991893/within-x-miles-search-in-mongodb) 4. isn't this [publicly accessible info](http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping between UK postcodes and latitude/longtitude is accessible online [on this site](http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php) in form of CSV so it should be easily parsed. In case it wouldn't be available latter for any reasons [I've mirrored it here](https://gist.github.com/lazyval/5181709).

As for your first three questions, as written [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991893/within-x-miles-search-in-mongodb) you can store entries like `case class Zip(code, location)` and perform lookup with `$near` operator on the second field.